# Calculate the limit : $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\tan ({\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}})^\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Exercise :**

> Calculate the following limit
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\tan \bigg({\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\bigg)^\frac{1}{x}$$

**Attempt :**

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} = \frac {1}{\infty} = 0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\tan ({\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}})^\frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\tan ({\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}})^0 = 1$$

Is  it correct ?

Comment: The power $1/x$ is inside the argument of the $\tan$ function or is it a power on the whole expression of $\tan$ ?

Comment: This is false since $\tan(0) =0$

Comment: The the thing is you can not evaluate the limit only on some part of the function. Which means, once you apply the limit you have to replace every variable with it's value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative

$$\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}=\frac{\frac{\pi}2 (2x+1)-\frac{\pi}2}{2x+1}=\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi}{4x+2}$$

then

$$\left[\tan \bigg({\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}}\bigg)\right]^\frac{1}{x}=\left[\cot \bigg(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\bigg)\right]^\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{\left[\tan \bigg(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\bigg)\right]^\frac{1}{x}} \to 1$$

indeed

$$\left[\tan \bigg(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\bigg)\right]^\frac{1}{x}=\left[\frac{\tan \bigg(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\bigg)}{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\right]^\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\right)^\frac1x\to 1^0\cdot 1=1$$

indeed

$$\left(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\right)^\frac1x=e^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\right)}{x}}=e^{\frac{\log \left(\frac{\pi}{4x+2}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{4x+2}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{x(4x+2)}}\to e^0=1$$

Comment: this one  is   Good and thanks  u @ gimusi...i have change my name  "Stupid"  to  'jasmine'

Comment: @jasmine That's a better name of course! Bye

Comment: @jasmine I delete the other answer, I don't like that so much and it is not much different from the one you accepted.

Comment: no problem @Gimusi,

Answer (score 4):

Write
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}-t=\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}
$$
When $x\to\infty$, we have $t\to0^+$ and also
$$
t=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi x}{2x+1}=\frac{\pi}{2(2x+1)}
$$
whence
$$
x=\frac{\pi-2t}{4t}
$$
The limit of the logarithm is thus
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{4t}{\pi-2t}\log\tan t=0
$$
and so your limit is $e^0=1$.

Just verify that
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\log\tan t=0
$$
which you should be able to.